# Fuses before or after vital components?

Tags: circuit-protection, fuses

Why are fuses/circuit breakers usually placed right after the power supply and before any critical components? Fuses are designed to be the first thing that melts or breaks down when there's too much current in the circuit so logically it shouldn't matter where you put it right?

The only reason I could think of why this might be better is that components will be separated from the power side of the battery and not the ground side which will minimize risk of random sparks or injuries if you happen to touch ground by accident and some component in the circuit at the same time.

Are there any other reasons that I'm missing?

Comment: It's hard - at least for me - to understand the core of your question. Could you maybe clarify your question by being more specific, like adding simple schematics "Why is it usually done like schematic A and not like schematic B?", for example?

Comment: Depends, but regulatory requirements would be my prime guess.

Answer (score 1):

> logically it shouldn't matter where you put it right?

And it doesn't (but see below), but have good luck finding the fuses if they are not where you expect them to be. Especially in a complex system.

A fuse can be anywhere in the circuit between the load and the source. It can be close to the source or close to the load - as long as it doesn't need to protect the wiring. Fuses and circuit breakers do protect the wiring, it's considered a part of the protected circuit. So in that case they must be in the electrical panel, not further down.